# VB.NET tableadapter.update() not updating database

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am trying to update records in a SQL DB from a VB.NET WF app and the tableadapter.update() command isn't working.

At least *part* of the problem I'm having is errors with the primary key. For some reason it won't let me update all of the column values except for the PK.

Here's my code for the "save" function, which is supposed to update the DB record based on  values in textboxes on the form.
as you can see from the code below I've tried a few different methods of updating, but none seem to work. any help you guys could provide in pointing me in the right direction would be helpful.

```
Try
            If Ds.main.Rows.Count <> 0 Then
                'send data to DT for editing

                'rows to write
                'Ds.main.Rows(searchIP.Text)("IP") = searchIP.Text
                'Ds.main.Rows(searchIP.Text)("HOSTNAME") = searchHost.Text
                'Ds.main.Rows(searchIP.Text)("SUBNET") = searchSubnet.Text
                'Ds.main.Rows(searchIP.Text)("VLAN") = searchVLAN.Text
                'Ds.main.Rows(searchIP.Text)("ALIVE") = searchAlive.Checked
                'Ds.main.Rows(searchIP.Text)("RESERVED") = searchReserved.Checked
                'Ds.main.Rows(searchIP.Text)("USR") = searchUser.Text
                'Ds.main.Rows(searchIP.Text)("NOTES") = searchNotes.Text
                'Ds.main.Rows(searchIP.Text)("FAIL") = searchFail.Text
                'Ds.main.Rows(searchIP.Text)("date") = Date.Now

                Ds.Tables("main").Rows(0).Item("notes") = searchNotes.Text

                'writes changes to DB
                Ds.AcceptChanges()
                Me.MainTableAdapter.Update(Me.Ds.main)

                ' refreshes the table on the All Hosts tab
                Me.MainTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Ds.main)


                ' clears all fields on the Search tab
                boxSearch.Text = ""
                searchIP.Text = ""
                searchHost.Text = ""
                searchSubnet.Text = ""
                searchVLAN.Text = ""
                searchUser.Text = ""
                searchNotes.Text = ""
                searchAlive.Checked = False
                searchReserved.Checked = False
                searchFail.Text = ""
                searchDate.Text = ""



                ' updates system message bar for 1 second
                Dim tmCurTime As DateTime = Date.Now
                Dim wait As Int16 = 1  ' Time in seconds
                Do
                    sysmsg.Text = "Saved!"
                    sysmsg.ForeColor = Color.Green
                    Application.DoEvents()
                Loop Until DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, tmCurTime, Date.Now) = wait
                sysmsg.Text = ""
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("error" + ex.Message)
        End Try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may need to remove this line:

```
Ds.AcceptChanges()
```

for more details of this method - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.acceptchanges(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: you're a legend mate. been working on this thing for so long my brain's gone all mushy. thanks!